# Using a list of dates to pull data from one DataFrame into another in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

I have a list of non-farm payroll dates in one DataFrame, the dtype is Object.  I want to pull all the 5-min data from my eurusd_ask DataFrame on those dates into a new DataFrame. Can someone help me figure out how to pass that list of dates into the following:

```
nfp_5min = eurusd_ask['2012-01-06']
```

instead of the specific date shown '2012-01-06',  I want to use a list of dates 'nfp_dates'

```
>>> nfp_dates.head(10)
         Date
0  2012-01-06
1  2012-02-03
2  2012-03-09
3  2012-04-06
4  2012-05-04
5  2012-06-01
6  2012-07-06
7  2012-08-03
8  2012-09-07
9  2012-10-05
```

My data looks like:

```
>>> eurusd_ask.head(10)
                        Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
Gmt time                                                       
2012-01-01 00:00:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:05:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:10:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:15:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:20:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:25:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:30:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:35:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:40:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:45:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
```

**Desired Result**

A DataFrame called nfp_5min and it would have all the 5-min eurusd_ask data for the nfp_dates.

Comment: Do you expect a conclusive answer without providing your data and expected output?

Comment: Sorry the Dataframe is large, here is what I am after:

nfp_dates
0

Comment: Please add the top 10 or top 15 rows to your dataframe. Use `df.head(10)` and add all info to your question.

Comment: Ok I added some of the data see if the question is easier to understand now

Answer (score 0):

An array to select the desired rows can be built with [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) and used like:

```
nfp_5min = eurusd_ask[np.isin(eurusd_ask.index.date, desired)]
```

#### Test Code

```
eurusd_ask = pd.read_fwf(
    StringIO(u"""
        Gmt time                Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
        2012-01-01T00:00:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-01T00:05:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-01T00:10:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-02T00:15:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-02T00:20:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-02T00:25:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-03T00:30:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-03T00:35:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-03T00:40:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
        2012-01-04T00:45:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0"""),
    header=1, parse_dates=['Gmt time']
).set_index('Gmt time')

nfp_dates= pd.to_datetime(['2012-01-01', '2012-01-02']).date

nfp_5min = eurusd_ask[np.isin(eurusd_ask.index.date, nfp_dates)]
print(nfp_5min)
```

#### Results:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
Gmt time                                                       
2012-01-01 00:00:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:05:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-01 00:10:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-02 00:15:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-02 00:20:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
2012-01-02 00:25:00  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496  1.29496     0.0
```